# Wordpress embed post

Tags: php, wordpress

I code my own Wordpress theme. And when I try to embed post, in front end I just have link title
[Blank embed post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyU9P.png)

But in admin editor I have this:

[Normal post embed view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMs0R.png)

The question is could you tell me how to fix this? I want to see embed post like in editor. Maybe I should add some them support in my functions.php?

Thank you

Comment: How are you getting the post's content? If you are using a `WP_Post` object manually you'll run into problems, but this should be automatic if you are in a loop and calling `the_content` or similar

Comment: My single.php dont have any loops. Just <?php the_content() ?>

Comment: Try calling `the_post();` before. You might have to wrap it in `while ( have_posts() )` which feels redundant since you are on a single, but it is what core does in their themes, too

Comment: Just tried to make this one, but still nothing <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post() ?>
<?php the_content() ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>